# How to send scheduled mail automatically from our android application?

Tags: android, email

I'm developing an application that sends mail to the entered recipient mail at the set time. The sender and the receiver are set static values. The application that sends mail from  on set time to the receiver mail id set static body and subject. Now how to make the mail send from independent mail account without intent interaction

Comment: for that i would suggest to use "Java Mail API", library and examples are available on the net, search for the same on google.

Comment: i checked that and it works for gmail alone. Do we have to configure account settings for different mail accounts?

Answer (score 0):

Without using Intents, you cannot send the Mail. I will suggest you to save your mail content in SQLite database, and create a Service that keep checks the time to send the mail after a particular time period, If it is a valid time thn send email in background using Intent.

Comment: Is it possible of using intent to send e-mail in background?

Comment: yes you can use Intent in Backgroud services, or like other members answered you can go for that also.. but it will be tad complex for you to implement.

Comment: Yes, I have implemented and it works for gmail account alone. I asked in such meaning that Without user interaction, is it possible to use intent to send mail  in the background service? Also i need to send mail without user interaction from all selected mail accounts of any type such as yahoo, hotmail, etc and  not only in gmail.

Comment: Yes you can use same line of codes in Service also, but for the first time you need user intersaction to start your Service,  It could be as simple as user just only needs to start you application only one... User a Timer that checks after a particular time suppose 30mins or 1hour or 1 Day as you like...